# Spark DataFrame orderBy and DataFrameWriter sortBy, is there a difference?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a difference in the output between sorting before or after the `.write` command on a DataFrame?

```scala
val people : DataFrame[Person]

people
        .orderBy("name")
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .format("parquet")
        .saveAsTable("test_segments")
```

and

```scala
val people : DataFrame[Person]

people
        .write
        .sortBy("name")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .format("parquet")
        .saveAsTable("test_segments")
```

Comment: Not really, I get that orderBy is a shorthand for sort on the DataFrame. But then is `sort`, before write any different than `sortBy` after write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different between those is explained on the comments within the code:

- orderBy: Is a Dataset/Dataframe operation. Returns a new Dataset sorted by the given expressions. This is an alias of the sort function.
- sortBy: Is a DataFrameWriter operation. Sorts the output in each bucket by the given columns.

The `sortBy` method will only work when you are also defining buckets (`bucketBy`). Otherwise you will get an [exception](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L546):

```
if (sortColumnNames.isDefined && numBuckets.isEmpty) {
  throw new AnalysisException("sortBy must be used together with bucketBy")
}
```

The columns defined in `sortBy` are used in the [BucketSpec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/catalog/interface.scala#L179) as `sortColumnNames` like shown below:

```
Params:
numBuckets – number of buckets.
bucketColumnNames – the names of the columns that used to generate the bucket id.
sortColumnNames – the names of the columns that used to sort data in each bucket.

case class BucketSpec(
    numBuckets: Int,
    bucketColumnNames: Seq[String],
    sortColumnNames: Seq[String])
```